# Rails - Errno::EACCES: Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, permission-denied

When I run rails s I get a permissions error

```
Ryans-MacBook-Air-2:fitbet ryankuhel$ rails s
/Users/ryankuhel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:37: warning: Insecure world writable dir   /Users/ryankuhel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin in PATH, mode 040777
```

then I got an error that I needed to run bundle install

```
Could not find debugger-1.6.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
Ryans-MacBook-Air-2:fitbet ryankuhel$ bundle install


Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/ryankuhel/documents/interactive/fitbet/.bundle/install.log
/Users/ryankuhel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler- 1.5.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/shell/basic.rb:345: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/ryankuhel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/Users/ryankuhel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:29:in `initialize': Permission denied - /Users/ryankuhel/documents/interactive/fitbet/.bundle/install.log (Errno::EACCES)
```

I am running Max 10.9.1. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: what are the permissions/ownership on /Users/ryankuhel/documents/interactive/fitbet/.bundle/install.log ?

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  21354 Dec 30 15:31 /Users/ryankuhel/documents/interactive/fitbet/.bundle/install.log

Comment: my guess is that you ran bundle install once as root, so now it can't write its log files.  Maybe delete that file?

Comment: Ryans-MacBook-Air-2:fitbet ryankuhel$ rails s
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:212: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/ryankuhel/.rvm/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:212: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/ryankuhel/.rvm/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Could not find debugger-1.6.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: i deleted the contents of the install.log and still got this error

Answer (score 4):

If you are running as user `ubuntu`, you can do `sudo chown ubuntu . -R` at the application root. This did the trick for me.